# How do I set a variable to a line in text doc to a variable Python 3.4.6

Tags: python, loops, variables, text, line

How would i set a line that I have found in a text document to a variable so that i can do things with it such as print that line or split that particular line.
In python 3.4.6

Comment: What is your issue? Opening the file? Finding the line? Storing it? Have you tried anything?

Comment: I know how to open the file and to get the code to find it the line but I am unable to get a variable to = the line that i have found in the text document

Comment: Could you show your code? (only the part that matters to the question, if the total program is big, see how to create a [mcve]) Use the "edit" button on the bottom-left of the question to modify it. Paste the code there

Answer (score 0):

```
recfile = open('/home/pi/Desktop/Recipt.txt', "a")
barfile = open('/home/pi/Desktop/Barcodes.txt').read()

if barcode in barfile:
    print("Your product has been found. ")
    while barcode in barfile:
        amount = input("How many do you want? ")
        print(barfile)

else:
    print("Your product was not found on our systems. ")
```